# Return an object method with the object context on JS (ES3)

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-3

I have this code:

```
function Selector(){
    this.name = 'Selector';
    this.select = function(fName){
        return this[fName]
    }

    this.funcOne = function(arg){
        console.log(arg + this.name)
    }

}
var mySelector = new Selector();
mySelector.select('funcOne')('Hello');
```

When I call `funcOne` with this implementation, the context within `funcOne` is the function itself, not the `Selector` instance. How can I maintain the context of the instance by calling funcOne in this way?

Edit: I'm using Extendscript, which is an ES3 environment, so I can't use bind() or arrow functions. What I need exactly is to be able to pass the parameters of the selected function separately, since the idea is, on one hand, to be able to select different functions with a number of different arguments, and on the other, to be able to chain calls using parentheses syntax:

```
function Selector(){
    this.name = 'Selector';
    this.select = function(fName){
        return this[fName]
    }

    this.funcOne = function(arg){
        console.log(arg + this.name)
        return this.select
    }

    this.funcTwo = function(arg1, arg2)
    {
        console.log(arg1 + arg2 + this.name)
        return this.select
    }
}
var mySelector = new Selector();
mySelector.select('funcOne')('Hello');
mySelector.select('funcTwo')('Hello ', 'my ')('funcOne')('Hello again ');
```

So using a pointer to the instance does not help either, since the problem with the context still remains:

```
function Selector(){
    var self = this
    this.name = 'Selector';
    this.select = function(fName){
        return this[fName]
    }

    this.funcOne = function(arg){
        var s = self; // undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: You can either bind the function to the context of `Selector` using `.bind(this)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or you can declare `Selector.prototype.funcOne` outside of the function constructor.

Comment: I'm using Extendscript, wich is an ES3 enviroment, so I can't use bind() or arrow functions

Comment: Functions are, generally speaking, scoped according to the object on which they’re called. So here, `mySelector.select` gets `mySelector` as its scope, but the result of that call, the function it returns, is detached from the object when it’s invoked, so it doesn’t get the `mySelector` scope. You can be explicit about the desired scope via `bind`, arrow functions (auto-binding), or by using `function.apply` or `function.call`.

Comment: The olde `self` trick worked since ES1: `var self = this; return function(arg) { self[fName](arg); }`.

Comment: `return this[fName].bind(this);`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, I readed that post before but it don't aswer my question. As I've mentioned, I can't use `bind()` or arrow functions. What I wan't exactly I to call the function using double parenthesis, not passing the arguments on the select `method` so `var self = this; return function(arg) { self[fName](arg); }`  don't solve my question, 
at least in the way that is proposed

Comment: alternative to bind for ES3:

`function bindFunc( thisValue, func) {
    return function() {
        func.apply( thisValue, arguments)
    };
}`

Comment: But     `var self = this;
 this.select = function ( fName) {
     return self[ fName];
    }` and using `self` instead of `this` in all the methods was a lot easier to get working ;-)